# Jquery Draggable into iFrame using connectToSortable = Helper / mouse position issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to put in place a Drag n drop system .
It's working but I have an issue with the position off the helper and the mouse. The mouse is on top of the drag item and the helper directly slide on top of the iFrame....so there is a gap between the mouse pointer position and the helper position.

Added to this, sortable (inside the iFrame) react to the mouse pointer when it is outside the iFrame....

here is the code I used

```
  $('iframe.preview').contents().find('body').sortable({
    items: '> *',
    iframeFix: true
  });

  $('.toolbar').find('li').draggable({
    appendTo: 'body',
    scroll: true,
    iframeFix: true, //Core jquery ui params needs for fix iframe bug
    iframeScroll: true, //This param needs for activate iframeScroll
    scrollSensitivity: 20,
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    connectToSortable: $('iframe.preview').contents().find('body'),
    cursorAt: {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    }
  }).disableSelection();
```

You can find and example here: https://jsfiddle.net/hatj8Lno/

Any idea how I can solve this behavior issue ?

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine in my browser (FF). Could you add a screenshot or a more detailed description?

Comment: I tried using FF and I have the same result than with Chrome. Mouse pointer is not aligned with the helper (it is positionned relatively the iframe and not the mouse). Please see the screenshot: ![Screenshot](http://hpics.li/8766236).